# Finding an old flight number

Tags: air-travel, airlines

How can I find an old flight number from over three years ago? I am trying to make a claim for a delay of over five hours. They sent us to the wrong destination and lost our luggage.

Comment: Insurance claim? Generally insurance policies only allow claims to go back 6-12 months max?

Comment: What information do you have for the flight? Airline, date, details?

Comment: Boarding pass? Paper itinerary? Travel agent? Maybe you booked through Expedia or something?

Answer (score 6):

Depending on the airline, you might be able to look up information at [FlighStats.com](http://www.flightstats.com/), though data older than a few days requires that you create a (free) account. [FlightAware](http://flightaware.com/) and [FlightWise](https://flightwise.com/flighthistory/) may also be of interest, though these require a paid account for historical data.